# Can gnome image viewer (eog) zoom and pan with keyboard ? Any alternatives who can?

Tags: gnome, image-viewer

I am using UBUNTU 16.04 LTS and so far use the default image viewer to view and examine high res photos. there i often need to quickly toom in and pan around using keyboard (if possible). i can zoom in and out using the num keybad + and - keys. but i yet did not found a way how to pan while zoomed , using keyboard only. cursor keys just flip to next or previous file.

i looked up the eog man page , help site, google for help on keyboard shortcuts and how to pan. did not found anything that helps me yet. also searched here , without luck.

Cant the "gnome image viewer" a.k.a. "eog" a.k.a. "eye of gnome" zoom and pan using keyboard?

Any tips for a nice image viewer like it, that DOES support zoom and pan ?

thanks
Axel

Answer (score 1):

grml... i just found the answer to my question on...

https://help.gnome.org/users/eog/stable/shortcuts.html.en

To zoom in and "pan" over the image using keyboard we will have to press and hold ALT + CURSOR Keys while zoomed.

the reason why i dint found it so far is that i did not used the wording "scrolling" instead of "pan" or "paning". duh

question solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in another viewer, give a try on [gqview](http://gqview.sourceforge.net/view-down.html) , its old but fast and lightweight; I think most of the systems now ship with [geeqie](http://geeqie.sourceforge.net/) a gqview spin-off, perhaps both are in your repos.

Good luck.

Comment: gqview was not found in the ubuntu 16.04 repos. but geeqie is. really nice tip!! thanks.