# What is the command-line name of Gnome's image viewer application?

Tags: gnome, images, file-browser

By default, images are opened from the Gnome file browser by an application which seems to be called "Image Viewer". I would like to use this application from the command line, but I don't know its name. And there don't seem to be any commands named `imageviewer`, `viewer`, or similar. What is this application's command-line name?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/184113/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/363746/117549

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`eog`

which stands for "[Eye of Gnome](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EyeOfGnome)"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that current GNOME Image Viewer is not Eye Of Gnome (`eog`), but Loupe (`loupe`).